# Facebook like AutoSuggest texbox using jquery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to implement Facebook like AutoSuggest texbox using jquery in my asp.net application.
I googled a lot about this but only found PHP links :( 
Any pointer or suggestion will be really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this link and download the autosuggestion file(jquery.fcbkcomplete.min http://www.emposha.com/ of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a specific example of the server-side code, do you?  I'd guess that using [this page](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) as a starting point, and using something like Fiddler to intercept the traffic from the page you should be able to figure out what is required on the back end...  (clue : autocomplete_ajax.cfm expects a query parameter called q with the text entered from the form, and returns data in the format

```
Match1Name|Match1Id
Match2Name|Match2Id
```

)

Comment: I need facebook like design , in which u can remove the text by clicking on the close button